# Reverse IP lookups return default reverse domain pointer

Tags: terminal, mac, macos, bash

Whenever I query ARPA for the reverse entry for an IP through the `host` command, I get a correct lookup result at first. Example:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-William-David:~ server$ host brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl
brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl has address 185.182.63.103
MacBook-Pro-van-William-David:~ server$ host 185.182.63.103
103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer **brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl.**
```

However, when I query multiple times in a short period of time, it simply returns the default reverse domain name pointer:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-William-David:~ server$ host brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl
brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl has address 185.182.63.103
MacBook-Pro-van-William-David:~ server$ host 185.182.63.103
103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer **103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa.**
```

Note the result of the lookup (`brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl` - `103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa`). Nothing has changed about the IP itself. This happens to lookups for other IP's as well.

`dig` works fine:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-William-David:~ server$ dig ptr 103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ptr 103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17414
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
103.63.182.185.in-addr.arpa. 14389 IN   PTR brc.nw1-ams1.mcxpro.nl.

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.254#53(192.168.2.254)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar  9 23:00:20 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 81
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the same problems with `dig -x <ip-address>`?

Comment: @klanomath No - `dig` is working correctly.

Comment: Still experiencing this issue...